# AddThis Toolbox and IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, addthis

I installed the AddThis toolbox on a client website.

One of my testers, using Internet Explorer 7, reports that two print icons appear in the toolbox row of icons.

Is anyone aware of any JavaScript issues in IE7 that could cause AddThis to have this unexpected behavior?

The toolbox HTML snippet is:

```
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_print"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
```

and the script links (bottom of page, before closing body tag) are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {services_compact: 'email,facebook,twitter,linkedin,print,more', data_track_clickback: true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4d9bb0c4086f82f7"></script>
```

If there is a known issue and one or more work-arounds, please share.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_print"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
```

That is the problem.
The tester has used addthis before, and has the print button in one of the 3 preferred buttons.
After the preferred buttons you force the print button on the user, thus the button appearing twice.